# MySQL Selecting multiple fields with one query that uses COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a doubt on a mysql query. Believe me I have googled a lot before coming and even searched SO but didn't exactly find the answer looking for. My question is, is the following statement considered proper as I am counting the rows, plus, also fetching the values of different fields?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, otp_code, otp_validity
FROM otp
WHERE otp_mem = :mem
```

Or, while using `COUNT(*)` should I not fetch the other field values in the same query? Is this a valid practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, otp_code, otp_validity
FROM otp
WHERE otp_mem = :mem
```

Why?  Your query is an aggregation query because it has `COUNT(*)`.  But, `otp_code` and `otp_validity` are in the `SELECT`, but not in the `GROUP BY`.

Presumably, you intend on of the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, otp_code, otp_validity
FROM otp
WHERE otp_mem = :mem
GROUP BY otp_code, otp_validity;
```

This returns one row per `otp_code`/`otp_validity` pair, with the counts for that pair.

Or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt, otp_code, otp_validity
FROM otp
WHERE otp_mem = :mem;
```

This returns every row with the overall count of rows returned by the query.

Or:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, MIN(otp_code), MIN(otp_validity)
FROM otp
WHERE otp_mem = :mem
GROUP BY otp_code, otp_validity;
```

This returns one row with sample values from the other columns.

Comment: so if I expect to return only 1 row I need to use `group by` and the rest is fine with the query, right?